# What is the correct way to add custom headers when calling REST-API from GraphQL Apollo-Server?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-datasource-rest

I tried to using below code, but it is failing to reach api with exception.

```
class CountriesAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseURL = "http://localhost:9321";
  }
// this is the area i want to add custom headers before graphql calls rest-api
  willSendRequest(request) {
    request.headers.set(

      "name", `Tat`
    );
    console.log(request);
  }

  async getAllCountries() {
    // return this.get("/getData");

    try {
      return this.get(`/getData`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

}
```

I have tried to get response from rest-api using custom headers concept but with the above code, apollo-server is failed to trigger request to rest-api with custom headers.

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to do the below:

```
willSendRequest(path,request) { request.headers['whatever'] ='whatever'; request.headers['whatever'] ='whatever'; }
```

Comment: It is good that you have answered your own question. However, It would be helpful to provide resources as to *why* this worked. Information as to where you solved this problem is crucial. Code-only answers without explanation are poorly received by the community. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: "Apollo Server 4 now uses the @apollo/utils.fetcher interface under the hood for fetching. This interface lets you choose your implementation of the Fetch API. To ensure compatibility with all Fetch implementations, the request provided to hooks like willSendRequest is a plain JS object rather than a Request object with methods." Read more https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/fetching-rest/#intercepting-fetches